# What Version of Javascript Engine, Rhino, is used for Bixby's Servers?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am writing a Javascript code for one of my Actions and It is complicated as it manipulates data structure of javascript object (written below) to search queries. How do I debug the code 
to make sure it works as intended. It consumes alot time for me so I was wondering if I could setup an IDE for myself. Sure I can use bixby itself to view the data output but sometimes it convenient to use console to check my code as I go along. I am not asking for recommendation, but I need clarify what the dev docs implies. It does mention that it use ES5.1 and some features too. but I don't know what that "some features" are by just looking at Mozilla's Rhino Compatibility chart. Because I did want to use .reduce(callback, initialValue) function to ouput data objects. However The Mozilla's Rhino Chart shows error for it.

PS: I Hope I am not breaking rules this time.

```
// #DataGraph 

  [{
    $id: "Cold_Souls_1",
    animeTitle: "Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood",
    animePoster:{
      referenceImage: 'https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-da58c837c7197acf364cb2ada34fc5fb.webp',
      imageTags: ["Grey","Yellow","Blue","Metal Body","Machine", "Robot","Yellow Hair Boy"],
    },
    animeCharacters:{
      "Edward Elric": [
        {
          quote: "A lesson without pain is meaningless. For you cannot gain something without sacrificing something else in return. But once you have recovered it and made it your own... You will gain an irreplaceable Fullmetal heart.",
          keywords: ["lesson", "pain", "meaningless", "gain","sacrificing", "recover"],
          category: "Life Lesson"
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you read from https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions Bixby IDE supports ECMAScript 5.1 and some ES6 such as:

- The arrow (=>) function operator
- The const keyword
- The let keyword
- Array destructuring

It is fair to say the functions not listed above are not supported.

I would recommend that you raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) in our community for unsupported features. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.